# How can I safely return a bash array over ssh?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, ssh

In the `bash` shell, arrays can be easily quoted with `declare -p`, then `eval`ed later to return them to normal. This seems acceptable for passing an array (as part of a script) to a remote machine over SSH.

The problem is, going the other way across the wire I don't want to expect the same level of trust. If the remote machine was compromised, an infection could spread to the local machine through unsanitised `eval` statements.

Currently, to pass arrays between machines I use an approach like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the modules we expect to find installed on the remote machine
expected_modules=(foo-module bar 'baz 2.0')

# SSH into the remote machine, send the arrays back and forth with "declare -p"
unparsed_missing_modules=$(ssh remote-machine /bin/bash << EOF
    check_for_module() {
        # Placeholder so that this can be tested locally
        case \$1 in
            foo*) true;;
            *) false;;
        esac
    }

    $(declare -p expected_modules)
    missing_modules=()
    for module in "\${expected_modules[@]}"; do
        if ! check_for_module "\$module"; then
            missing_modules+=( "\$module" )
        fi
    done

    declare -p missing_modules
EOF
)

# Unpack the result (this is what I want to find an alternative to)
eval "$unparsed_missing_modules"

# Do something with the result after unpacking into an array
for module in "${missing_modules[@]}"; do
    echo "Warning: Remote machine is missing $module" >&2
done
```

The primary insecurity in this script is near the end, when the output of a `ssh` session is passed directly to `eval`. How can I sanitise this input in `bash`?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that no expected module contains a newline in its name? If so, I wouldn't bother trying to encode an array in either direction; just use a multi-line list of module names instead.

Comment: As an aside, instead of `<< EOF`, you may be better off using `<<'EOF'` to pass the script literally, and passing arguments in literally on the remote shell's command line rather than substituting them into the script text; less room for data on your local machine to expand into code on the remote end.

Comment: ...a technique I'm demonstrating in my answer. :)

Comment: @chepner, sure, that's presumably safe (certainly safe from a security perspective), but since the question may be reused by someone who doesn't have that guarantee wrt range of valid data, why not do it right and cover all valid C strings?

Comment: I didn't feel like writing up a fully correct answer (I was pretty sure I'd get some detail wrong), so I just wanted to suggest an alternative that was easier to implement. Plus, I was pretty sure you'd be along soon to provide the right answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generic, safe answer is to NUL-delimit your array's entries, pass the literal NUL-delimited data over stdout, and use a `while read` loop to interpret it.

Observe:

```
get_remote_array() {
  local args
  local hostname=$1; shift
  printf -v args '%q ' "$@"
  ssh "$hostname" "bash -s $args" <<'EOF'
# in real-world use, print something more useful than the arguments we were started with
# ...but for here, this demonstrates the point:
printf '%s\0' "$@" 
EOF
}

array=( )
while IFS= read -r -d ''; do
  array+=( "$REPLY" )
done < <(get_remote_array "localhost" \
            $'I\ncontain\nnewlines' \
            'I want to $(touch /tmp/security-fail)' \
            "'"'I REALLY want to $(touch /tmp/security-fail), even in single quotes'"'")

echo "---- Shell-escaped content"
printf '%q\n' "${array[@]}"

echo "---- Unescaped content"
printf '<<%s>>\n' "${array[@]}"
```

This demonstration passes potentially malicious data in both directions, and demonstrates that it survives the round-trip unharmed.